# Error with Spring application

Tags: java, spring, jar

I am trying to deploy a spring application. As soon as I deploy I get the below errors. What is the cause? The application is a Dynamic Web Project
I am using eclipse and I am deploying the application in Tomcat . Thank you in advance. Please let me know is any other information is required in answering this question.

```
                    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
                org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in class com.canon.cusa.cla.config.AppConfig: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'proxyCachingConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'proxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: void org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.Collection); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.canon.cusa.cla.config.HibernateConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
                    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
                    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
                    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
                    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
                    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'proxyCachingConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'proxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: void org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.Collection); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.canon.cusa.cla.config.HibernateConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:452)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:353)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
                    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
                    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:100)
                    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:84)
                    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:107)
                    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:353)
                    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
                    ... 40 more
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'proxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: void org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.Collection); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.canon.cusa.cla.config.HibernateConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:353)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
                    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
                    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:100)
                    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:84)
                    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:107)
                    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:278)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:880)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:852)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:446)
                    ... 62 more
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: void org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.Collection); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.canon.cusa.cla.config.HibernateConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
                    ... 86 more
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.canon.cusa.cla.config.HibernateConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:748)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:551)
                    ... 88 more
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.canon.cusa.cla.config.HibernateConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
                    ... 99 more
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
                    ... 101 more
```

Below are the jar files I am using in this application

```
activation.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
aspectjrt.jar
aspectjtools.jar
aspectjweaver.jar
autonomyClient.jar
AutonomyUtilities.jar
cglib-2.2.2.jar
com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
com.springsource.org.quartz-1.6.2.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.3.jar
commons-email-1.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-lang-2.3.jar.deleted
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.6.jar
cwsagent.jar
cwsapi.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-core-2.5.1.jar
ehcache-web-2.0.4.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate3.jar
httpclient-4.1.3.jar
httpclient-cache-4.1.3.jar
httpcore-4.1.4.jar
httpmime-4.1.3.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.5.4.jar
jackson-core-lgpl-1.5.4.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.5.4.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.4.jar
jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.5.4.jar
jackson-xc-1.5.4.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar
jsr250-api.jar
jstl.jar
jta-1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
mail.jar
nw3s-service.jar
ojdbc14.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
pager-taglib.jar
serializer.jar
simplecaptcha-1.1.1-jdk1.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar
standard.jar
struts2-core-2.1.6.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
xalan.jar
xdb.jar
xmlparserv2.jar
```

Below is my web.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

        <display-name>CLA</display-name>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- specify app config file for listener. config locations consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited 
             and fully-qualified @Configuration classes --> 
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.config.WebConfig</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener--> 
        <listener>
              <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>     

        <!-- Declare a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as usual -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <!-- Configure DispatcherServlet to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext 
                instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
                <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <!-- map all requests for / to the dispatcher servlet -->
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <!-- Declare a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as usual -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>captchaServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.CaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <!-- map all requests for / to the dispatcher servlet -->
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>captchaServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/captcha</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.util.web.XSSFilter</filter-class>     
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <!-- Error logging filter --> 
        <filter>
            <filter-name>ClaApplicationFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.web.ErrorHandlingFilter</filter-class>        
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>ClaApplicationFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <!-- UTF-8 Encoding Filter -->
        <filter>
            <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Comment: Error is "`No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found`". Where do you believe you defined your `DataSource`, i.e. the object that specifies how to connect to your database (JDBC URL, user, password, ...)? *Hint:* Can't define it in `web.xml`, so I don't know why you showed us that file.

Comment: What db do you want to connect to? You are probably missing the connector for your db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs, the application cannot successfully connect to a database simply because it cannot find a DataSource or there isn't one at all.

```
Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.canon.cusa.cla.config.HibernateConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

So the approach will be to define the DataSource that can be detected by the spring application on startup.

Here is a bean definition that works for MySQL

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

And for Oracle, since I saw the driver in your list (assuming Oracle SID = XE)

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```